# Add a link to the Admin menu

Tags: admin, admin-menu

I would like to add 2 lines to the POSTS menu in the wordpress admin:  Published and Scheduled.  I would also like to add a section to the media menu for Unattached media.  How would I go about doing this?

Cheers[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept the global `$submenu` var and add the desired elements:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_submenus', 999);

function add_custom_submenus() {
  global $submenu;
  $submenu['edit.php'][] = array(
    __('Published'), // menu title
    'edit_posts', // menu cap
    'edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post' // menu link
  );
  $submenu['edit.php'][] = array(
    __('Scheduled'),
    'edit_posts',
    'edit.php?post_status=future&post_type=post'
  );
  $submenu['upload.php'][] = array(
    __('Unattached'),
    'upload_files',
    'upload.php?detached=1'
  );
}
```